# Jquery table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This code produces a mess... What am I doing wrong?

```
 cell=$("<td>");
        if(normal.exam_type=="Exam_Boolean")
        {
            var input=cell.append("<input>").last();

            input.attr("type","hidden");
            input.attr("name","exam.exam_Normal['" +normal_id_unique + "'].boolean_v");
            input.attr("value",normal.normal_boolean);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
var cell = $("<td></td>");
if(normal.exam_type=="Exam_Boolean")
{
    $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("name", "exam.exam_Normal['" +normal_id_unique + "'].boolean_v")
          .attr("value", normal.normal_boolean)
          .appendTo(cell);
);
```

[newlines before dots are just for readability.]

You might also need to put the cell in the document somewhere before appending stuff. I'm not sure

Comment: it seems to work...
However appendTo doesnt seem to return a reference to $("input />")

Comment: it totally should. What does it return then? log it to firebug and take a look

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using [`cell.append(input)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) - which returns a reference to `cell` - try doing it "the other way around" as [`input.appendTo(cell)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
var cell = $("<td>");
if(normal.exam_type=="Exam_Boolean")
{
    var input= $("<input />").appendTo(cell);
    input.attr("type", "hidden");
    input.attr("name", "exam.exam_Normal['" + normal_id_unique + "'].boolean_v");
    input.attr("value", normal.normal_boolean);
);
```

Comment: gives me  a jquery exception :(

Comment: @Parhs: Why, where? It looks ok to me.

Comment: At the jquery.js file...
But i fix the problem if
var input= $("<input>").appendTo(cell); 
    input.attr("type", "hidden");

var input= $("<input>");
    input.attr("type", "hidden");
input.appendTO(cell);

Comment: That does not seem to make much sense. Closing the `<input />` element might, though, as shown in the updated answer. Anyhow, I see you have found your solution, so I will not bugger you anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends what you want the code to do. If you want to append the input after the last item in cell, then try:

```
cell=$("<td>");
if(normal.exam_type=="Exam_Boolean")
{
    var input=cell.last().after("<input>");

    input.attr("type","hidden");
    input.attr("name","exam.exam_Normal['" +normal_id_unique + "'].boolean_v");
    input.attr("value",normal.normal_boolean);
};
```

If this does not do what you desire, maybe you should post some of the html code and a better description of what you want your code to do.